# ¿Alguien me puede explicar que hace este codigo?

Tags: python, condiciones, bucles, matemáticas, indices

```
l = [ 1, 10, 4, 2, 4, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3]    
# moda                                                                                   
repeticiones = 0                                                                         
for i in l:                                                                              
    apariciones = l.count(i)                                                             
    if apariciones > repeticiones:                                                       
        repeticiones = apariciones                                                       

modas = []                                                                               
for i in l:                                                                              
    apariciones = l.count(i)                                                             
    if apariciones == repeticiones and i not in modas:                                   
        modas.append(i)                                                                  

print "moda:", modas
```

Comment: A simple vista, parece estar evaluando la cantidad de veces que un grupo de elementos se repiten en el arreglo `l`... Precisamente que te interesa saber? Solamente que hace, o como lo hace?

Comment: Si estás llevando algún curso en un instituto o universidad, te sugiero revisar el sílabo y las referencias bibliográficas, esto es algo que muy pocos hacen...

Answer (score 4):

Al ver el código se aprecia dos partes, siendo la segunda la que filtra las modas de acuerdo a la frecuencia máxima encontrada en la primera parte.

Aquí el análisis para `l = [ 1, 10, 4, 2, 4, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3]`. Sólo hay que aclarar que las posiciones en las listas  empiezan a contarse desde cero (`0`).

### Primer Parte

```
# Primer Parte
repeticiones = 0
for i in l:
    apariciones = l.count(i)
    if apariciones > repeticiones:
        repeticiones = apariciones
        print(i, apariciones, repeticiones)
        # se imprime
        # 1 3 3
```

La función `l.count(i)` cuenta los elementos que hay en la lista `l`, en la primera iteración `i es igual a 1` porque es el elemento de posición cero de `l[0]`... `print(l[0]) # se imprime 1`

En ese momento la variable `apariciones` toma el valor de `3` porque en la lista `l` se repite el número `1` tres veces.

Luego se tiene el condicional `if`, dado que la variable `repeticiones` inicialmente es cero (`0`) la expresión `apariciones > repeticiones` será `True` y `repeticiones` se le asignará el valor de `3`, en tal sentido se obtiene la secuencia 1, 3, 3 `(l[0], apariciones, repeticiones)`

Y cuando se llega a la sexta posición `l[5]=3` -*recordar que empieza en cero el conteo*-, el `3` se repite tres veces entonces como ya repeticiones vale `3` en el condicional `if` se tiene la siguiente expresión `3>3`, esto será `False` y no se detectará que el número tres (`3`) de la lista `l` también.

> Resumiendo la **primera parte** funciona para detectar **la mayor frecuencia**, pero sí existen elementos en la lista, que tienen la misma frecuencia, se tomará, el dato del elemento más próximo a la posición cero (`0`) de dicha lista.

### Segunda Parte

```
# Segunda Parte
modas = []
for i in l:
    apariciones = l.count(i)
    if apariciones == repeticiones and i not in modas:
        modas.append(i)

print( "moda:", modas)
# Se imprime
# moda: [1, 3]
```

Este código busca en concreto, cuales son las modas -*incluso repetidas*-, en tal sentido, lo relevante de la **segunda parte**, es la expresión que va dentro del condicional `if`:

```
apariciones == repeticiones and i not in modas
```

Como `repeticiones` es igual a tres (`3`) -*valor tomado de la primera parte*- se itera de nueva la lista `l`

Entonces verbalizando la primera iteración se tiene:

```
¿3==3 "y" 1 "no está" en la lista modas?
```

Es el equivalente a `True and True` dará `True` porque `1` no está incluido en la lista `modas` dado que dicha lista está vacia en esta instancia.

Luego verbalizando la sexta iteración `l[5]`, -*recordar que empieza en cero el conteo*-

```
 ¿3==3 "y" 3 "no está" en la lista modas?
```

Es el equivalente a `True and True` dará `True` porque `3` no está incluido en la lista `modas`.

Entonces se tiene una especie de candado con `i not in modas` porque a partir de la séptima posición empiezan a aparecer los elementos `1` y `3` que ya fueron incluidas en la lista `modas`, por tanto ya no es necesario incluirlas con la función `modas.append(i)`, la cual las va insertando a la lista `modas` conforme van identificándose los elementos, su equivalente sería:

```
modas.insert(len(modas)+1,i)
```

> Resumiendo, en la **segunda parte** se verifica que elementos coinciden con el máximo número de repeticiones obtenido en la **primera parte**, es decir se garantiza que la lista `modas` incluya los números con la mayor frecuencia, cuando existe más de una moda.