# No efectua la matriz transpuesta en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrices, bucles, indices

Si hago una matriz no me deja hacer la transpuesta, pero si ya tengo una matriz vacia si me hace la transpuesta.

def TranspuMa(matriz):

```
if ValidaMatrices(matriz) == False:
    return "No es una matriz"

else:
    NM = [[0]]
    M2 = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
    while len(matriz[0]) != len(NM[0]):
        NM[0] += [0]
    while range(len(matriz)) != range(len(NM)):
        NM += [NM[0]]
    x = -1
    y = -1

    for i in range(3):
        x+=1
        for j in range(3):
            y+=1
            M = matriz[i][j]
            NM[y][x] = M


        y = -1



    print(M2)
    print(NM)
```

Comment: Es mejor que pongas el codigo como texto  y no como imagen, es mas facil para la gente probarlo y ayudarte

Answer (score 1):

## Consideraciones

Creo que si se quiere una [matriz transpuesta](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matriz_transpuesta), podría tratarse de dos formas:

1. Mediante una **función anónima** (se incluye para complementar la pregunta)
2. **Iterando sobre las celdas** de la matriz, lo cual puede abordarse de tres maneras:

   2.1. Empleando bucles `while` anidados

   2.2. Empleando bucle `for` anidados

   2.3. Empleando la compresión de listas anidadas

Como no se ha proporcionado la función `ValidaMatrices` voy a asumir que se está ingresando una matriz correcta sin necesidad de ser filtrada por dicha función.

## 1) Función Anónima

Para crear dicha función, se necesita del operador (`*`) y de las funciones `zip`, `list` y `map`.

A continuación se tiene la siguiente matriz: `matriz=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]`, cuya transpuesta es `[[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]`

```
print zip(*matriz) 
#[(1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6)]
```

A primera vista se aprecia que la función **zip** toma los elementos de cada lista o fila y las agrupa primeros con primeros y segundos con segundos, asimismo el operador (`*`) fragmenta (`desempaca`) las filas de la matriz antes de ser tratadas por `zip`. Aquí el detalle:

```
fila1=[1,2]
fila2=[3,4]
fila3=[5,6]
print zip(fila1,fila2,fila3)
#[(1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6)]
```

Observar que `zip(*matriz)` produce dos **tuplas** o dos filas que son **tuplas**: `(1, 3, 5),(2, 4, 6)` en tal sentido, la función **list** convierte las tuplas en listas.

```
print list((1,3,5)), list((4,5,6)) 
#[1, 3, 5] [4, 5, 6]
```

Asimismo mediante la compresión de listas se facilita agrupar nuevamente las **tuplas** transformadas a listas en la matriz respectiva.

```
print [list(i) for i in [(1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6)]]
#[[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]] 

print [list(i) for i in zip(*matriz)]
#[[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
```

Adicionalmente **Python** cuenta con la función **map** la cual requiere dos parámetros:

```
 map(funcion, iterables)
```

Lo anterior puede visualizarse a continuación

```
print map(list, [(1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6)])     #[[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
print map(list, zip(fila1,fila2,fila3))     #[[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
print map(list, zip(*matriz))               #[[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
```

> Resumiendo, **el corazón** de la función anónima es: **map(list, zip(*matriz))**

```
# Funcion anonima
mt = lambda m: map(list, zip(*m))

for r in mt(matriz): print(r)
# Se imprime:
# [1, 3, 5]
# [2, 4, 6]
```

## 2) Iterando sobre las celdas

A continuación vemos un desarrollo más tradicional para obtener la transpuesta

#### Empleando bucles `while` anidados

```
# Empleando bucle while anidados
def TranspuMaV1(matriz):
    m=matriz

    nFil=len(m)
    nCol=len(m[0])

    # siendo i las filas y j las columnas
    mt=[]
    j=0
    while j<nCol:
        i=0
        mt.append([])

        while i<nFil:
            mt[j].append(m[i][j])
            i+=1

        j+=1

    return(mt)
```

#### Empleando bucle `for` anidados

```
# Empleando bucle for anidados
def TranspuMaV2(matriz):
    m=matriz

    nFil=len(m)
    nCol=len(m[0])

    # siendo i las filas y j las columnas
    mt=[]

    for j in range(nCol):
        mt.append([])
        for i in range(nFil):
            mt[j].append(m[i][j])

    return(mt)
```

#### Empleando la compresión de listas anidadas

```
# Empleando la compresión lista anidada
def TranspuMaV3(matriz):
    m=matriz

    nFil=len(m)
    nCol=len(m[0])

    # siendo i las filas y j las columnas
    mt=[[m[i][j] for i in range(nFil)] for j in range(nCol)]

    return(mt)
```

#### Probando las tres alternativas

```
# Pruebas       
matriz=[[1,2],
        [3,4],
        [5,6]]


for r in TranspuMaV1(matriz): print(r)
print()
for r in TranspuMaV2(matriz): print(r)
print()
for r in TranspuMaV3(matriz): print(r)

# Se imprime:
# [1, 3, 5]
# [2, 4, 6]

# [1, 3, 5]
# [2, 4, 6]

# [1, 3, 5]
# [2, 4, 6]
```

Asimismo sugiero se revise [estructura de datos](http://docs.python.org.ar/tutorial/2/datastructures.html) en **Python**, para ver en detalle cómo funciona `list.append`. Adicionalmente en [¿Alguien me puede explicar qué hace este código?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/247454/alguien-me-puede-explicar-que-hace-este-codigo) detallé como se indexan las listas en **Python** y explico qué hace el método `list.append`

Finalmente, después de la acotación anterior, nótese que para crear cada fila en la matriz transpuesta, se inserta una lista vacia `[]` en `mt` con el método `append`, excepto en la tercera propuesta.

> **Nota:** En este caso se han presentado variantes para resolver lo solicitado, no obstante, ninguna de éstas, ha sido sometida a rendimientos de ejecución, -*por ejemplo en matrices de 1000x1000*-, en tal sentido, considero que esto, ya escapa a la pregunta inicial, al no preguntarse por algoritmos que traten lo anterior.